# How do i send values to web service?

Tags: xml, web, soap, service, client

How do i create the parameters to be sent in the following structure with the Header?

I am using php to send values to a `.net` web service. I used the Boomerang extension with Chrome and works fine; it prints success with `xml` as response.

I have tried the following using my localhost:

```
<?php
try{

$client = new SoapClient("http://test");

$auth = "<x:Header><ts><id>?</id><Idcliente>?</Idcliente><fecha>?</fecha> 
</ts><x:Header>";
$auth_block = new SoapVar( $auth, XSD_ANYXML, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

class ServiceHeader{}
$serviceHeader = new ServiceHeader();
$serviceHeader->id = '?';
$serviceHeader->Idcliente = "?";
$serviceHeader->fecha = "?";

$header = new SoapHeader("http://test", "xxxx", $serviceHeader);
//$header = new SoapHeader( $ns, 'Header', $auth_block );
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$params->Idcliente = '?';
$params->Idsolicitud = '?'; 
//etc   
$result = $client->AddObject($params)->AddObjectResponse;

}

catch(SoapFault $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();//Prints malformed petition from response
}
?>
```

This is what the web service expects to receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" 
xmlns:aon="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Aon.Policy.Model" 
xmlns:aon1=
"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Aon.Policy.Model.Employee.Add">
<soapenv:Header>
<ts>{"id":"?TEST","IdCliente":"?TEST","fecha":"?TEST"} </ts> 
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tem:AddObject>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <tem:request>
        <aon:IdCliente>648</aon:IdCliente>
        <aon:Fechamovimiento>2016-01-07T00:00:00-06:00</aon:Fechamovimiento>
        <aon:Fechasolicitud>2016-01-07T00:00:00-06:00</aon:Fechasolicitud>
        <aon:Idsolicitud>1</aon:Idsolicitud>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <aon1:employee>
           <aon1:TEST1/>
           <aon1:TEST2>0</aon1:TEST2>
           <aon1:TEST3/>
           <aon1:direccion>
              <aon:colonia/>
              <aon:numero/>
              <aon:codigopostal/>
              <aon:calle/>
           </aon1:direccion>
           <aon1:certificado>?</aon1:certificado>
           <aon1:TEST4>?</aon1:TEST4>
           <aon1:dependientes>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <aon:Dependiente>
                 <aon:certificado>?</aon:certificado>
                 <aon:Idcertificado>?</aon:Idcertificado>
                 <aon:TEST5>?</aon:TEST5>
                 <aon:genero>?</aon:genero>
                 <aon:TEST6>?</aon:TEST6>
                 <aon:apellido>?</aon:apellido>
                 <!--Optional:-->
                 <aon:segundoapellido>?</aon:segundoapellido>
                 <aon:nombre>?</aon:nombre>
              </aon:Dependiente>
           </aon1:dependientes>
           <aon1:TEST7>?</aon1:TEST7>
           <aon1:numerodearchivo>0</aon1:numerodearchivo>
           <aon1:genero>0</aon1:genero>
           <aon1:apellido>?</aon1:apellido>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <aon1:segundonombre/>
           <aon1:correo/>
           <aon1:estatusmatrimonial>?</aon1:estatusmatrimonial>
           <aon1:nombre>?</aon1:nombre>
           <aon1:Idpaquete>?</aon1:Idpaquete>
           <aon1:telefono/>
           <aon1:TEST8>?</aon1:TEST8>
        </aon1:employee>
     </tem:request>
  </tem:AddObject>
  </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Does the Soap Header really expects a JSON string?

Comment: I believe is expecting that but i trying to set it with setSoapHeaders. or may be send in different way with json?

Comment: You can find out all webservice methods types by [__getFunctions()](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getfunctions.php) and [__getTypes()](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.gettypes.php). Search for a `ts` struct in the given types from the webservice. There 's defined, how it should look like. Guessing and believing is not an option for working with webservices.